# angular 2 ui-router: change data in parent state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a project using Angular 2 and **UI-ROUTER** (not NgRoute).

It has:
    a parent state 'parent', controlling the view of *Header* and *Control* as shown in the picture below,
    two child states 'childA' and 'childB', controlling the view of *child*  [image]

On entering any of a child state say 'childAState', I need to pass some text like 'childA', to the *header* view that controlled by parent state. How can I do it? How to pass data to parent state when entering a child state?

This 'childA' text is not related to any component, but related to the child state it's entering. ( So I don't think I should pass it through component tree.)

I defined the states like this:

```
export const parentState = {
    name: 'parent',
    url: '',
    redirectTo: 'childA',
    views: {
        'header': {
            component: HeaderComponent
        },
        'control-panel': {
            component: ControlComponent
        }
    }
};
export const childAState = {
    name: 'childA',
    parent: 'parent',
    url: '/childA',
    views: {
        'child@': {
            component: LayerAComponent
        }
    }
};
export const childBState = {
    name: 'childB',
    parent: 'parent',
    url: '/childB',
    views: {
        'child@': {
            component: LayerBComponent
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have service with `BehaviorSubject` . Parent will be observing that service data .

When child component wants to inform parent, it updates the service . Since parent is observing the service data it gets notified and performs action. This is one of the ways components communicate in angular, you can use that method.

Comment: If I use BehaviorSubject, where should I trigger it? since I need to pass the data when entering the child state, should I use something like onEnter for the child state and do dataBehaviorSubject.next('someData')?

Comment: Yes something like that

Answer (score 2):

Put data on your states' `data` property, like this example:

```
export const childAState = {
    name: 'childA',
    parent: 'parent',
    url: '/childA',
    data: {
        childData: 'childA'
    },
    views: {
        'child@': {
            component: LayerAComponent
        }
    }
};
```

In your `HeaderComponent` you can listen to state changes, either using a Transition Hook or the `router.globals.success$` observable.

```
import { TransitionService } from '@uirouter/angular';

@Component({})
class HeaderComponent {
  private unsub: Function;
  constructor(public transService: TransitionService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.unsub = this.transService.onSuccess({}, transition => {
      const to = transition.to(); // The state that was just activated
      if (to.data && to.data.childData) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsub();
  }
}
```

or

```
import { UIRouter } from '@uirouter/angular';

@Component({})
class HeaderComponent {
  private sub: Subscription;
  constructor(public router: UIRouter) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = router.globals.success$.subscribe({}, transition => {
      const to = transition.to(); // The state that was just activated
      if (to.data && to.data.childData) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```